# Can I comment an inline CSS style?

Tags: css

Can I comment an inline CSS style? Like this:

```
<main style="/* color: lime; */">Hello!</main>
```

It work but I can not find the spec

Comment: Yes it works but not advisable :-)

Comment: so you've answered your own question. Weather you can or can't find the specification is not related to the question yoou've actually asked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612909/comments-within-style-attributes-safe

Comment: Yes, as google chrome DevTools also do the same type of commenting in inline css